# Hidden/Dark Pool Hedge Funds

Tags: investing, hedge-fund

Is there a noun for investment funds which do not disclose the assets they are investing in to their customers?

Some exchanges are called "Dark Pools" where the orderbook is hidden to traders, so I thought there might be a similar noun for hidden investment strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a noun for investment funds which do not disclose the assets they are investing in to their customers?

Hedge fund?

Other than 13F filling requirements( US specific) I don't really know any that make their entire book public to their investors.

But to directly answer the question I haven't heard of a term that is meant to describe this.  It just happens to be that almost all hedge funds are as secretive about their holdings as possible until  its in their best interest to make it public ala the olive garden break stick manifesto

http://www.usatoday.com/story/money/business/2014/09/12/olive-garden-darden-starboard-value/15510761/

Comment: I understand that hedge funds do not disclose their portfolios in public, I was referring to not disclosing their holdings/investment strategy to their customers.

Comment: @emcor, sorry for the late reply but manyh hedge funds don't disclose their holdings or strategy to their clients.